# In Android 4, does disabling "Show notifications" have an effect on the process priority with regards to low memory?

Tags: notifications, ram

Android 4 has a feature where you can disable notifications for an app by going to that app's properties and unchecking a checkbox. Both temporary and ongoing notifications will be hidden.

My question relates to low memory situations. If your device is low on memory, it will selectively kill processes to regain memory. Apps not in the foreground will go first. Apps that have a persistent notification have higher priority (though they, too, may be killed in extreme cases).

Many utility apps, like [tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm), [llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama), [Juice Defender](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.latedroid.juicedefender), and others have an in-app ability to disable the ongoing notification icon. They all stress, however, that hiding the icon will cause their respective app to be more likely to be killed if there is low memory.

If I select to hide the notifications within the app properties, the app (presumably) doesn't know that it is being silenced.

If I hide the notifications via app properties, does the app therefore get pushed to a lower priority when memory is low? Or does the persistent notification simply get hidden, but is still running and giving the app the higher memory priority?